# Have Error while try to Update Ember 2.14.2 to Ember 2.18.2

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Anyone please help me with Ember update.My current code base was 2.14.2 and I try to update 2.18.2.And I got the below error.

```
Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Cannot find module 
'/sampleApp/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js'
```

Anyone, please guide me with this. If you have another method to upgrade the version of ember please let me know or please help to solve the issue.

**Update**

Full stack track:

Log File Source

`ENV Summary:

ERROR Summary:

```
- broccoliBuilderErrorStack: [undefined]
- code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
- codeFrame: [undefined]
- errorMessage: Cannot find module 
'/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/bower_components/ember/ember- 
template-compiler.js'
- errorType: [undefined]
- location:
- column: [undefined]
- file: [undefined]
 - line: [undefined]
- message: Cannot find module 
'/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/bower_components/ember/ember- 
 template-compiler.js'
 - name: Error
 - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
 - nodeName: [undefined]
 - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
 - stack: Error: Cannot find module 
'/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/bower_components/ember/ember- 
template-compiler.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Class.htmlbarsOptions (/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/node_modules/ember-inplace-edit/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/ember-addon-main.js:78:25)
at Object.toTree (/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/node_modules/ember-inplace-edit/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/ember-addon-main.js:31:36)
at /Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:180:26
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at processPlugins (/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:178:11)
at module.exports.preprocessTemplates (/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:161:10)

=================================================================================
```

Ember-Cli version of the project :

```
ember-cli: 2.14.2
node: 10.13.0
os: darwin x64
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you update? Have you tried to incrementally update?

Comment: what version of `ember-cli` are you using?

Comment: Hi @Lux I'm using https://embermap.com/video/how-to-upgrade-an-ember-app-or-addon way to update an ember.

Comment: Hi @mistahenry I have updated my question.Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember experiencing something like this around the late 2.x of ember. Basically, ember switched from bower to npm around 2.11 or so.

Are you using the `ember-source` npm version of `ember`? Your template compiler lookup is searching within `bower` which is most likely wrong if you've properly made the switch to `npm`, which you should have!

There's this [issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/6711) that was fixed which may be the cause for you. Often times, updating the ember 
version alone isn't enough. For me, it was always easiest to update to the ember-cli version whose blueprint installed the version of `ember` that you are wanting (which will help you know what other core dependencies need updating). Looking through old release notes helps here.

If you are using an old ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompiler, you need to upgrade to:

```
 "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.6"
```

If it's not either of those, please update your question with the full stack trace and the `ember-cli` version

EDIT: I'd like to help enable you to solve this issue yourself in the future so here's the detailed breakdown of how I reach my conclusion. In your stack trace, we see:

```
/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/bower_components/ember/ember- 
template-compiler.js
```

This is looking for `ember` in `bower` which is no longer the case since you have `ember-source` in your `package.json`. This error results from

```
at Class.htmlbarsOptions (/Users/mariselvan/Documents/sampleApp/node_modules/ember-inplace-edit/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/ember-addon-main.js:78:25)
```

So the conclusion here is that the version of `ember-inplace-edit` is old and you need to upgrade or fix yourself. Look at this addon's [package.json](https://github.com/anilmaurya/ember-inplace-edit/blob/master/package.json) and it's got this fixed dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.9" // this was released Jun 12, 2015 
}
```

For the record, my ember 2.18 app bundled `"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1"` by default. So lets go to the release of [0.7.9](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-htmlbars/releases/tag/v0.7.9), download the source code, and look at the offending line in :

```
templateCompilerPath: function() {
    var config = this.projectConfig();
    var templateCompilerPath = config['ember-cli-htmlbars'] && config['ember-cli-htmlbars'].templateCompilerPath;

    if (!templateCompilerPath) {
      // THIS ONLY WORKS FOR BOWER VERSIONS OF EMBER
      templateCompilerPath = this.project.bowerDirectory + '/ember/ember-template-compiler'; 
    }

    return path.resolve(this.project.root, templateCompilerPath);
  }
```

So you have a couple of reasonable options

1. Fix the addon and make it support later Ember versions and open a PR to get merged upstream (by updating this ember cli htmlbars dependency)
2. Fork the addon and fix it without merging upstream and point to your fork
3. Remove the addon and rework this part of your application
4. use the `templateCompilerPath` option to point to your `ember-source` version (but this is honestly the worst option)

Comment: I tried what you said.I have updated my question please refer that

Comment: Nicely done. This is the problem with the addon. Thank's for the help